# Set a default value in constructor

Tags: solidity

Ok. So I know this should be easy to do, I simply want to set a default value in the following:

```
uint8 public gasPriceLimit;     //Gas Price Limit

//Constructor
constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals) public {
  name = _name;
  symbol = _symbol;
  decimals = _decimals;
  uint8 gasPriceLimit = 999;
}
```

However, doing this I get the following error when compiling:

```
Type int_const 999 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint8.
```

I also tried setting in the declaration itself without luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok. A mystery to me, but if I change to use uint instead of uint8 then the following works fine:

```
uint public gasPriceLimit = 999;
```

Comment: `uint8` has 8 bits, so the maximum value it can store is `2^8 = 256`. `999 > 256`, so you need a bigger integer. `uint16` should be sufficient, but `uint256` (which `uint` is an alias for) is fine.

Comment: But note that you need to change the first declaration of `gasPriceLimit`, and then in the constructor, you just want `gasPriceLimit = 999`. Your current code declares a new variable that shadows the existing one, so it doesn't actually update the state variable.

Comment: ah yep.. good point and just saw that in the compiler as well :) Cheers